# VMware vSphere ESXi 6 and Horizon View 6 with PXE clients

Tags: virtualization, esxi, pxe

I have used VMware vSphere ESXi server 6 trial with vCenter server and vSphere client 6 on Windows Server 2012 R2 locally and I could successfully get them to work, but I want to go one step further and try Horizon View 6 too for studying purposes.

Horizon View client can be run on a guest OS or through HTML5-based web browsers to access the console, but I want to know how to access the hosted guest OS on ESXi server using a thin client or a laptop with the support of PXE, so the guest thin client or laptop will not have an OS installed on them and instead use PXE to boot the guest OS hosted on ESXi Server. Is it possible with VMware vSphere 6 and Horizon View 6? What other options do I have with VMware products to run the guest OS hosted on ESXi Server on a client without any OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizon View client can be run through HTML5-based web browsers to access the console. Then you could PXE boot "any" Linux live distro and start its Web browser pointing to the Horizon View URL.

You will need a PXE server that could also be run from an ESXi's guest. This PXE server is the one that will offer the above mentioned Linux live distro for PXE booting.

If you need a self contained automated PXE Server see [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html). (I'm related to Serva development)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with Linux but If you're suggesting me to use a live Linux distro so why do i need to setup a PXE server? I could simply put a Linux live distro in a flash memory and run it through the USB port of a guest client which can be a thin client, laptop or PC andrun it. right?

Comment: You said you want to `PXE` the client; then `you need a PXE server`. You said `the laptop will not have an OS installed` then you `need to boot a live OS`, this is easily done only with Linux and not with Windows. If you change your question and you do not need PXE anymore then you could boot a Live Linux distro from your USB Pendrive in your thin client, laptop or PC

Comment: Yes you're right, when i made my question I didn't really consider the fact that If my clients don't have an installed OS I can use a live Linux distro. I think It's better to use your solution than using a PXE server so that things will be much more simplified. I'm marking your answer as accepted but can you suggest the best Linux distro that I can use as live OS for my situation? I need a Linux live distro that is as simple and light as possible and has the latest version of browsers like Chrome or Firefox which can be updated later.

Comment: Btw, You said I can PXE boot any Linux live distro. well why should i PXE boot a live OS? Isn't using a live Linux distro on a USB pendrive a more reasonable option ?

Comment: It depends on your scenario and needs... if you want a flexible scenario, not dependable on having always available a booting pen drive, and you also need FAST booting times then PXE is your only option. If you do no care about the previous factors you can go with the Pendrive alternative.